# Fetch data from the 3 subclasses in the same request and return the result in a Page object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities (Child1, Child2, Child3) which extends the same class (Parnt). The 3 entities differ by a few fields.

Models

```
//lombok annotations
@MappedSuperclass
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String City;
    private Date date;
}
```

```
//lombok annotations
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    private Obj1 obj1;
}
```

```
//lombok annotations
public class Child2 extends Parent {
    private Obj1 obj2;    
}
```

```
//lombok annotations
public class Child3 extends Parent {
    private Obj1 obj3;
}
```

Repositories

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ParentRepository <T, ID extends Serializable>  extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {}
```

```
public interface Child1Repository extends ParentRepository <Child1, Long> {}
```

```
public interface Child2Repository extends ParentRepository <Child2, Long> {}
```

```
public interface Child3Repository extends ParentRepository <Child3, Long> {}
```

The problem is I want to fetch data from the three children in the same request and return the result in a `Page<Parent>` object sorted by date.

Example: if we request `localhost:8080/api/result?page10&Size4`, the result should be

```json
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "city": "Roma",
            "date": "2022-06-06 10:42:12",
            "obj1": {...
            }
        },{
            "id": 11,
            "city": "Milano",
            "date": "2022-06-06 10:45:12",
            "obj2": {...
            }
        },{
            "id": 102,
            "city": "Delhi",
            "date": "2022-06-06 10:45:20",
            "obj1": {...
            }
        },{
            "id": 92,
            "city": "Sale",
            "date": "2022-06-06 10:49:13",
            "obj3": {...
            }
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "unsorted": false,
            "sorted": true,
        }
        "pageSize": 4,
        "pageNumber": 10,
    },
}
```

Comment: One approach is, get the data paged individually from three repos, get the overall count (assuming the counts on all repos are same) and Build page object using PageableExecutionUtils with data and the count

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: @Siva Rahul , It is not possible because the three tables will be filled arbitrarily